# How Get xml content from xml Ip api and display it on webpage?

Tags: javascript, xml, ip

I am using XML api of http://ip-api.com/docs/api:xml on my webpage to get information about a visiter visiting my website.
following is the successful xml document returned from their api :

```
<country>United Kingdom</country>
<countryCode>UK</countryCode>
<region>Bristol</region>
<ip>xx.xx.xx.x</ip>
<ISP>VodafoneM</ISP>
```

I want to show content of this xml document on my webpage using javascript, I know it can easily be done using a server side language like PHP, My php version is old and it's returning error for parsing an xml document. So I am looking for a client side solution.

Here is what I have tried so far :

```
<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://ip-api.com/xml/xx.xx.xx.x");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("country")[0]y=x.childNodes[0];
document.write(y.nodeValue);
</script>
```

It doesn't work, I am getiing a blank page.

How can I display the content of xml file on my webpage?

Please help me, I have been trying to solve this since morn

Comment: try to load xml document like this: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted your code as follows:

```
    //txt = loadXMLDoc("http://ip-api.com/xml/xx.xx.xx.x");
    var txt = '<country>United Kingdom</country><countryCode>UK</countryCode><region>Bristol</region><ip>xx.xx.xx.x</ip><ISP>VodafoneM</ISP>';
    txt = '<query>' + txt + '</query>';

    // Info: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
    }
    else // Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
    }

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("country")[0];
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
    //document.write(y.nodeValue);
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = y.nodeValue;
```

Please check the result in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marianc/emrjnzy9/).